# Call flatpage from with a view

Tags: python, django

Can I call a Flatpage from with a view.  Say I have some code like:

```
def myview(request):

  if request.subdomain != "www":
    return HttpResponseRedirect("http://"+request.subdomain+".mydomain/login/")

  else:
    call the flatpage here...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You sure can. Just make sure you have the `flatpage` function included in your view code:

```
from django.contrib.flatpages.views import flatpage
```

And stick the following in your `else:`

```
return flatpage(request, '/path/to/your/flatpage/')
```

Or if you'd like to configure the flatpage to use the same URL being called, you can always do it like this:

```
return flatpage(request, request.path)
```

I just tested this and it worked just fine. Let me know if it doesn't for you.